# Relation Between Brigsby Bear and Future Folk?

Tags: reference, brigsby-bear

The [Future Folk (folk band)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Folk) and the relevant film, [the history of future folk](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245195/?ref_=rt_li_tt) (2012), revolve around a narrative about the duo coming to Earth from another planet. The costumes that they use in the film and their concerts are like this:

[image]

Recently I watched [Brigsby Bear](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5805752/?ref_=nv_sr_1) (2017), and a guy with a very similar costume appears:

[image]

I was wondering if this is a reference to Future Folk or if it was inspired somehow. 
Future folk have made a [reference in their fb page](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=177612495629553&story_fbid=1447447441979379v) but I still did not understand if the two films are associated. Any ideas?